# php5 fpm consuming lot of CPU

Tags: php, php-fpm

My problem is with php5-fpm processes which are consuming a lot of CPU. Any single request from my website is resulting in CPU consumption of minimum of 20% to the max value. I've observed many times even index.php page consumes upto 70% of the CPU. So multiple requests on server ultimately lead to the 100% cpu utilization and for unknown duration the CPU remains at 100% The website is hosted on aws infra where webservers are running under autoscaling and loadbalancing environment using nginx and php5-fpm.

Sine multiple servers are running in autoscaling, so the above behavior is observed on multiple server(not all) at the same time.

Currently , the content of www.conf file is as below:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 100
```

I have also tried with "ondemand" process manager but no luck(followed [this](https://ma.ttias.be/a-better-way-to-run-php-fpm/) link).

Please help me out.

**Update1:**

Thanks. 
I'm facing this problem on an eCommerce website so we can get an idea what kind of scripts it would be using.
I have checked with php script to print hello. Most of the time its showing 0% consumption of cpu but 've found weird readings  of 356.63 also shown below.

```
30810   Idle    30/Apr/2015:11:03:30 +0530  466 93  2804    GET /hello.php  0   -   /mnt/www/Lecom_Magento/hello.php    356.63  524288
31162   Idle    30/Apr/2015:11:19:33 +0530  280 43  472 GET /hello.php  0   -   /mnt/www/Lecom_Magento/hello.php    0.00    524288
```

Below is the top command output when cpu utillization was 100%.

```
top - 11:02:59 up 23:58,  2 users,  load average: 22.60, 23.10, 21.48
Tasks: 253 total,  13 running, 240 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 64.5%us, 31.8%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  30759072k total,  9692172k used, 21066900k free,   325488k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  5487396k cached
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                      
30157 www-data  20   0  916m 432m  39m R   92  1.4   7:44.66 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30177 www-data  20   0  913m 429m  36m R   90  1.4   7:40.15 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30326 www-data  20   0  555m  78m  42m R   89  0.3   1:45.19 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30462 www-data  20   0  553m  71m  35m R   88  0.2   0:30.93 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30393 www-data  20   0  555m  78m  40m R   86  0.3   0:51.62 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30793 www-data  20   0  542m  50m  25m S   85  0.2   0:10.91 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30454 www-data  20   0  550m  60m  27m R   80  0.2   0:29.87 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30342 www-data  20   0  555m  75m  37m S   77  0.3   2:00.78 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30416 www-data  20   0  554m  73m  35m S   74  0.2   0:39.84 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30369 www-data  20   0  554m  72m  35m R   64  0.2   1:32.15 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30350 www-data  20   0  555m  76m  38m S   63  0.3   1:38.23 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30388 www-data  20   0  552m  71m  35m S   62  0.2   1:08.40 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30799 www-data  20   0  548m  55m  24m R   55  0.2   0:01.77 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30792 www-data  20   0  555m  71m  33m S   50  0.2   0:05.49 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30391 www-data  20   0  553m  70m  34m R   44  0.2   1:15.94 php5-fpm                                                                                                     
30333 www-data  20   0  554m  77m  39m S   40  0.3   1:38.81 php5-fpm
```

**CPU configuration**: c3.4xlarge aws ec2 instance having 16vCPU and 30GB memory.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SF. At the moment your question is quite vague. There are too many possible answers. Please try to investigate a bit more. Tell us more about your scripts (what is it, what does it do, is your load high even with very simple script - like hello world - , what is the response time on it). Also some information on what does the load actually look like (header of `top` command + few php lines). Then it might be easier to come up with an answer, or with more questions for you to investigate.

Comment: ok so how much CPU you have??

Comment: Thanks Fox and ADM :)
 I've updated the question according to your inputs. Would it be helpful?

Comment: @Navjot did you figure this out?